# Fundamental Misunderstanding About CORS and Ajax Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have code that works, but I'm having a difficult time making the connection as to *why* it works.

I have code in an AngularJS factory function that makes this call:

```
$http.get('http://webServerName/PrestoWebApi/api/apps/')
```

And this is the Web API controller (C#):

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://webServerName", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class AppsController : ApiController
```

The source of the call would be a user's computer, for example, a laptop with the name **JoesLaptop**. And that laptop could run anywhere. (Currently, this is all running inside one LAN, but the user could be anywhere.)

So why does specifying the **web server name** within the `EnableCors` attribute work? Isn't the request coming from the browser on Joe's laptop and not from the web server itself?

**Edit**

If I remove the `EnableCors` attribute, I get this error in the F12 tools in the browser:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://webServerName/PrestoWebApi/api/apps/`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://webServerName'` is therefore not allowed access.

**Edit 2**

Request:

```
GET http://fs-6103.fs.local/PrestoWebApi/api/apps/ HTTP/1.1
Host: fs-6103.fs.local
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://fs-6103
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://fs-6103/PrestoWebApi/app/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://fs-6103
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 18:30:05 GMT
Content-Length: 2931171
```

Comment: "The source of the call would be a user's computer". Incorrect. The HTTP request (script) is initiated by the user through the UI, but the origin of the call is from the server that's hosting the webpage. [Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Ah, so that's what I was missing. Since that's the case, why would I need the `EnableCors` attribute that specifies the web server name, when it's all running on the same server? Why would that be a cross-domain request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `webServerName` is rendering an HTML page that is starting an asynchronous request to `webServerName`, then `CORS` doesn't apply and your server will serve that resource anyway.

I'm pretty sure that must be your case.

## UPDATE

Based on the latest edits of the question and the comments that the OP has made bellow this answer, this is what must be happening.

The HTTP server that it's serving both the main HTML page and the API resource is the same, therefore there shouldn't be any need to `EnableCORS`. However, according to the headers of the `Request` the page is being served from `http://fs-6103` and the `$http.get` is made to `http://fs-6103.fs.local`. That should explain everything.

## UPDATE 2

Ok, I'm willing to bet that this is what's happening here:

- The main page is being served by `http://fs-6103`
- The `$http.get` is made towards: `http://fs-6103.fs.local/`

**So far I'm not speculating, this is what the request is saying**

The OP must have `[EnableCors(origins: "http://fs-6103", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` set into the API controller.

When this is disabled the OP is getting the error:  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, as it should be expected. And when the  OP enables it everything works as expected.

Comment: Then shouldn't it work if I remove the `EnableCors` attribute? It doesn't. See my edit.

Comment: @BobHorn interesting! But could you please confirm whether the original page is served by the `webServerName` or if it's served by a `localhost` server in the same "clients" computer? Is the original page served by `JoesLaptop` or by `webServerName`?

Comment: The pages are all served by `webServerName`.

Comment: @BobHorn aha! and what's the URL that the user uses for accessing the page? Does that URL look like `http://webServerName/MainPage` or like `http://192.168.1.100/MainPage` or do they have a record in their host file and they access it like this: `http://TheMainServer/MainPage`?

Comment: @BobHorn and if you remove the `EnableCors` attribute it doesn't work?? That's hard to believe, because that's not a cross origin request, both requests come from the same origin! Could you please share the headers of that request? (Both the request and the response headers, specially the response headers)

Comment: Add headers to my post.

Comment: There you go! Compare the value of  `host` and value of `origin`

Comment: Why would they be different? The host has the domain suffix on it, so why wouldn't the origin?

Comment: @BobHorn no problem, I'm glad that I was able to help you out, please have a look at my latest update, I was making it while you accepted my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I actually changed the `$http.get` to not include `.fs.local` but the request still needed the `EnableCors` attribute. Go figure. At least I can tell by the headers now why this is happening. Like you said, maybe it's a DNS thing.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers/clients handle the security, and generally restrict things to single origin, meaning they only accept stuff from the server they made the request to. Enabling cors in the header (ACAO) or wherever lets that server tell the browser, "hey those other Cross origin resources are with me." The browser will generally go along with that.

Comment: Okay, so the browser only accepts stuff from the server it made the request to. Since the browser is making a request to `webServerName`, why is the `EnableCors` (specifying `webServerName`) attribute necessary?

Comment: So `server` didn't match the request `origin`, even though any reasonable person would expect it to.